# When is it appropriate to use index_scan for getting data already sorted?

Tags: sql, postgresql, sorting, indexing

Is there some rule of thumb? The thing is I just came up with the issue, where index doesn't help to run query faster with its predefined sort. I have the following table `tbl`:

```
|  p_id  |   s_id  |  w_id   | amount  | currency_id |          date              |
|integer | integer | integer | numeric |   integer   | timestamp without time zone|
```

The table contains approximately `500k` rows and I need to execute the following query on it:

```
SELECT p_id, s_id, w_id, amount, currency_id
FROM (
    SELECT p_id, s_id, w_id, amount, currency_id, 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY p_id, s_id, w_id ORDER BY date DESC NULLS LAST) rn
    FROM tbl
) sbt
WHERE sbt.rn = 1
```

Without having any indexes on the table the planner choose the following to do:

```
Subquery Scan on sbt  (cost=68369.47..90802.76 rows=2991 width=19) (actual time=616.402..958.030 rows=253657 loops=1)
  Filter: (sbt.rn = 1)
  Rows Removed by Filter: 344564
  ->  WindowAgg  (cost=68369.47..83324.99 rows=598221 width=27) (actual time=616.397..909.711 rows=598221 loops=1)
        ->  Sort  (cost=68369.47..69865.02 rows=598221 width=27) (actual time=616.384..642.357 rows=598221 loops=1)
              Sort Key: tbl.p_id, tbl.s_id, tbl.w_id, tbl.date
              Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 71313kB
              ->  Seq Scan on tbl  (cost=0.00..10969.21 rows=598221 width=27) (actual time=0.038..111.827 rows=598221 loops=1)
Total runtime: 967.421 ms
```

and on my data it takes 7 secs averagely. I thought, that sorting is a very expensive operation so it's defenitely better to use `index scan` instead of `seq scan + sort`. But If I create an appropriate index:

```
CREATE INDEX text_idx
  ON tbl
  USING btree
  (p_id, s_id, w_id, date DESC NULLS LAST, currency_id, amount);
```

in order to do `Index Only Scan` the plan will be the following:

```
Subquery Scan on sbt  (cost=0.00..56853.58 rows=2991 width=19) (actual time=167.895..747.224 rows=253657 loops=1)
  Filter: (sbt.rn = 1)
  Rows Removed by Filter: 344564
  ->  WindowAgg  (cost=0.00..49375.82 rows=598221 width=27) (actual time=167.889..693.238 rows=598221 loops=1)
        ->  Index Only Scan using test_idx_to_drop on tbl  (cost=0.00..35915.84 rows=598221 width=27) (actual time=167.876..365.174 rows=598221 loops=1)
              Heap Fetches: 598221
Total runtime: 752.713 ms
```

Looks great, but it didn't help too much to improve performance. The average time of the query execution is now 6.8 secs. I started to look into I/O stats (`pg_statio_user_tables`, `pg_stat_user_table`) of the table and what I've figured out is that:

In the case of `index scan` here is the statistics (cold cache):

```
idx_scan   idx_tup_fetch   heap_blks_read    idx_blk_read
   1          598221          4987              3819
```

and `sort+seq` scan

```
seq_scan   seq_tup_read   heap_blks_read
   1          598221          4987
```

***QUESTION:*** Is there a more-or-less short rule where to use index for sorting and where it won't be good. Is in the case of my table using index really inapropriate to avoid sorting?

Comment: You full scan over 500k rows, twice. It would take some time. PS: what is the corresponding `EXPLAIN ANALYZE`? The index improved the cost: twice overall and down to 0 for the first row. It's a significant improvement.

Comment: @zerkms What do you mean EXPLAIN ANALYZE?  I provided more complete statistic about the queries than just `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)`

Comment: Your query eliminates sorting and the analyze shows that. What exactly your question is about? "What do you mean EXPLAIN ANALYZE?" --- I mean it literally, what is the output for `EXPLAIN ANALYZE`?

Comment: Explain analyze for seq scan shows that it also requires 71MB to perform quick sort on the table. Is that what you meant?

Comment: Nope, I was curious about the exact timing of the first row to come available. If it's `~0ms` vs `5s` then the latter solution **IS** an improvement (and I'm even more lost on why you ask the second question then)

Comment: @zerkms I replaced just `ANALYZE` with `EXPLAIN ANALYZE`. Couldn't you look at it?

Comment: So, `616ms` vs `168ms`, that definitely is an improvement. PS: I would not put those many columns (without additional check if covering index makes real difference in this case).

Comment: @zerkms it's what the planner shows. Actual execution takes 6.8 secs and 7 secs.

Comment: `ANALYZE` shows you the actual execution time. Those are `957ms` and `753ms` correspondingly. Everything else is the network (?) overhead: you need to transfer those 250k+ rows, it's not instant and it's not what you can improve with indexes.

Comment: @zerkms I believe that because of 500k rows being fetched we got such overhead... (network latency, probably) Maybe it be the cause of such divergence?

Comment: No, it's because those 250k rows need to be transferred to your client. 752ms is how long postgresql need to generate the whole data set (with 168ms spent for the initial row), everything else is delivering it to the client.

Comment: @zerkms Aahhhhhhhhhhhh, so it's just network latency overhead that is not shown by the planner, right?

Comment: `(actual time=616.402..958.030 rows=253657 loops=1)` your plan says it was ~253k rows fetched :-S

Comment: Not latency specifically, but latency + bandwidth I suppose.

Comment: @zerkms It seems I understood your point. On such large amount of data the transmition time takes too much and it's not shown by the planner. Planner shows the only it spend for data-related operations (sorting, aggregating etc). So, I actually got good performance improvement but didn't notice it because the transmission time took 10 times more than data-related operation. If so, I think it may be useful not only for me. Maybe you can post it as an answer so I'd accept it?

Comment: Okay, will try to make something concise yet helpful in next few minutes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we compare the output for the `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` which additionally to the cost provides the actual timings we would see that the query from

```
Subquery Scan on sbt  <skipped> (actual time=616.402..958.030 rows=253657 loops=1)
<skipped>
Total runtime: 967.421 ms
```

has improved to

```
Subquery Scan on sbt  <skipped> (actual time=167.895..747.224 rows=253657 loops=1)
<skipped>
Total runtime: 752.713 ms
```

Which means that initial query has improved from `~616ms` to `~168ms` to obtain the first row, and from `~967ms` to `~753ms` to generate the whole data set.

As of per your observations of `7s` and `6.8s` to obtain the whole data set on your client is because it takes time to transfer several hundreds of thousands of rows over the network: the latency and bandwidth are finite and limited, hence bring some delays in data delivery.

Additionally to what I said I would suggest you to try to reduce the index to only `p_id, s_id, w_id, date DESC NULLS LAST` columns and see if the performance is still acceptable. The [index-only scans](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Index-only_scans) topic is a bit blurry to me so I personally prefer to check it on my data set first.

Comment: Very interesting wiki-page about index only scans, thanks much.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using version >= 9.3, then you can try lateral subquery:

```
SELECT x.*
FROM (
   SELECT DISTINCT p_id, s_id, w_id FROM tbl
) t, 
LATERAL (
   SELECT p_id, s_id, w_id, amount, currency_id
   FROM tbl t1
   WHERE t1.p_id = t.p_id AND t1.s_id = t.s_id AND t1.w_id = t.w_id
   ORDER BY p_id, s_id, w_id, date DESC NULLS LAST 
   LIMIT 1
) x
;
```

with new index only on subset of columns:

```
CREATE INDEX text_idx_new
  ON tbl
  USING btree
  (p_id, s_id, w_id, date DESC NULLS LAST);
```

---

Lateral subqueries are part of SQL Standard, 
at the present time - as I know - they are implemented by Oracle 12c, IMB DB2, MS SQL Server and PostgreSQL 9.3.
You can find the documentation here: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/queries-table-expressions.html

Topic named: **7.2.1.5. LATERAL Subqueries**

---

The lateral subquery uses `ORDER BY ... LIMIT 1`, and PostgreSql can use an index to optimize this kind of queries (unlucky I can't find any documentation on this topic for PostgreSql, their documentation is poor in contrast to Oracle where they have very detailed documentation on how their optimizer works).
Since your query picks only 2991 rows from among 598221, that is 0.4% (very few), so it means that there are only 2991 distinct grops, and the lateral subquery will be performed only 2991 times. 
I think it worth to give it a try, because it may perform better.

---

You are right,  `DISTINCT p_id, s_id, w_id` requires data to be sorted, however there is index created on these columns, and this index contains already sorted data, so PostgreSql will only scan this index to obtain distinct groups, without sorting.

Comment: Please, correct me if I wrong. I think that it's not too fast to use DISTINCT in the query because it requires data to be sorted (cannot use hashing as far as I know). So, don't we get an additional overhead with such a query? Also, it would be appreciate if you provided some reference to the `LATERAL` and how it works. I have not faced with it before.

Comment: I've updated the answer with some additional information, please take a look at it.

Comment: "Since your query picks only 2991 rows from among 598221" --- it picks 250k+. 2991 is an estimation.